# wrong number of arguments in product comments in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am trying to add comments to my product and when i submit my comment i get this error

"ArgumentError in Products#show

Showing C:/Sites/project/app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb where line #3 raised:

wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2)"

MY PRODUCT/SHOW.HTML.ERB

```
<body style="background-image:url('/images/Linux Wallpaper.jpg');">

<div class="panel panel-default panel-list" style="width:70%;margin:20px auto;background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);">
    <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:rgba(126, 232, 173, 0.78);">
        <h3 class="panel-title" style="font-family:lucida;display:bold;">
        <% if @product.user == current_user %>
          <p style="float: right;"><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_product_path(@product), :style=>"background-color:rgb(10, 245, 61);padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;border-radius: 6px; border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);"  %> </p>
<%end%>
          <p style="float: left;"><%= link_to 'Back', products_path, :style=>"background-color:rgb(10, 245, 61);padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;border-radius: 6px; border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);" %><p>
           <center>YOUR PRODUCT : <%=@product.title%></center> 
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.1);">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-4" style="padding-left:30px;">
            <%= image_tag(@product.img_url.url(:large),:style => "height:400px;width:800px;border-radius: 4px; border:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.9);") %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
              <strong style="color:yellow;font-size:2em;font-weight:bolder;">Name:</strong><br>
            <div style="color:lightgreen;font-size:2em;">
            <%= @product.title%>
                </div>
        </div>
             <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
              <strong style="color:yellow;font-size:2em;font-weight:bolder;">File Type:</strong><br>
            <div style="color:lightgreen;font-size:2em;">
            <%= @product.filetype%>
                </div>
        </div>
<div style="float:right;padding-right:10%;">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2">
  <strong style="color:yellow;font-size:2em;font-weight:bolder;">Price:</strong><br>
        <div style="color:lightgreen;font-size:2em;">
  $<%= @product.price %>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;padding-right:10%;">
<div>
  <strong style="color:yellow;font-size:2em;font-weight:bolder;">Tags:</strong><br>
        <div style="color:lightgreen;font-size:2em;">
  $<%= @product.all_tags %>
        </div>
        </div>
<div>
<h2><%= @product.comments.count %> COMMENTS</h2>
<p><%= render @product.comments %></p>
<h3> ADD A COMMENT </h3>
<p><%= render 'comments/form' %></p>
</div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

MY COMMENTS_CONTROLLER

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @product=Product.find(params[:product_id])
        @comment=@product.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:body))
        redirect_to product_path(@product)
    end
end
```

_COMMENT.HTML.ERB

```
<p><%= current_user.name %></p>
<p><%= comment.body %></p>
<p><%= time_ago_in_words.(comment.created_at)%></p>

<p><%= link_to 'Delete',[comment.product,coment], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
</p>
```

Comment: The error says `ArgumentError in Products#show` there is the `show` action? Could you post it?

Comment: Not the _views_, the action _code_.

Comment: obviously in the `Products` controller.

Comment: The error is in the `_comment` partial it seems, can you show that.

Comment: sorry i thought i did , my bad

Comment: the problem is clearly in <%= time_ago_in_words.(comment.created_at)%>

Comment: thats because if i display just comment.created_at it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra dot after `time_ago_in_words` from this line

```
= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at)
```